# Test reporting in selenium WebdriverJS with node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriverjs

We have requirement to automate application using selenium with Javascript. Im familiar with Selenium with Java but completely new to JS. I have started exploring WebdriverJS using nodeJS. How can we have test reporting for webdriverJS? Is there any framework that will give good UI reporting.
Kindly assist.

Thank you